# How to use ObjectMapper to read a JSON file having the content map of maps?

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have a JSON file that has the following structure:

```java
Map<Enum1, Map<Enum2, Map<Enum3, Map<Enum4, Map<Enum5, Map<String, String>>>>>>
```

How do I read the content of the file into the above map structure?

I have tried the following, but Eclipse gave an error `The type Map is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String>`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

TypeReference<Map<Enum1, Map<Enum2, Map<Enum3, Map<Enum4, Map<Enum5, Map<String, String>>>>>>>
        typeRef =
        new TypeReference<Map<Enum1, Map<Enum2, Map<Enum3, Map<Enum4, Map<Enum5, Map<String, String>>>>>>>() {
        };

mapper.readValue(file, typeRef);
```

The content of the file looks like this:

```json
{
  "enum1": {
    "enum2": {
      "enum3": {
        "enum4-1": {
          "enum5-1": {
            "example1": "example1 string",
            "example2": "example2 string"
          },
          "enum5-2": {
            "example1": "example1 string",
            "example2": "example2 string"
          }
        },
        "enum4-2": {
          "enum5-1": {
            "example1": "example1 string",
            "example2": "example2 string"
          },
          "enum5-2": {
            "example1": "example1 string",
            "example2": "example2 string"
          }
        }
        ....
      }
      .....
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could just make the top level `TreeMap<String, Object>`, then cast down the values as needed as you call `.get()`, however, might make more sense to stay with `JsonNode` rather than use a Map at all

Comment: @OneCricketeer do you mean I should not use `Map<Enum1, Map<Enum2, Map<Enum3, Map<Enum4, Map<Enum5, Map<String, String>>>>>>` at all, instead, i should use TreeMap?

Comment: No, you need an instance of a Map as the actual `readValue` return type. HashMap or TreeMap, doesn't matter. For the TypeReference, you really don't need to go deeper than the top object type.

Comment: @OneCricketeer so it will be like this?

`TypeReference<HashMap<LanguageEnum, Object>>
  typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<LanguageEnum, Object>>() {};

HashMap<LanguageEnum, Object>  ret = mapper.readValue(file, typeRef);`

Comment: You should use `Map` with `TypeReference`. I was only saying the return type of `readValue` is a specific implementation of a Map interface

Comment: @OneCricketeer tried with Map on `TypeReference` and got Type mismatch from Map to HashMap

Comment: Generally, I don't use TypeReference, i use the factory. Also, I don't know how enums work as key values, but try `mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapLikeType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you very much!